# Reading contents of a text file and saving them to specific class objects

Tags: java, variables, text-files

Hi there guys I have a simple text file that looks something like this:

```
20 20
1 0 18 0
1 10 18 10
4 5 15 5
```

Where the first two integers are my games width and height and the remainder are coordinates for obstacles on the map I am creating. My question is I need to assign the first two integers to class variables WIDTH and HEIGHT and then just save the remaining integers in a form of Array list for which i can access later. Mainly Im just confused on how to setup my readfile to be able to save everything to its appropriate Objects. Thank you for the help and any tips on posting is also appreciated as Im just learning how to correctly post onto stack.  
 

So far all I have setup is the opening and closing of the file, my readfile method is blank because I keep testing new ways.

```
public void openFile() {
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(new File(gameMap));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("File was not found");
    }
}

/**
 * Reads the gameMap file and sets variables accordingly, made singular so i can read multiple maps later
 */
public void readFile() {
    while (scan.hasNext()) {

    }           

}   
/**
 * Closes map file, set singular so I can close multiple maps later on
 */
public void closeFile() {
    scan.close();
}
```

Comment: Well, you could start with some code. Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: show me, how your reading text file

Comment: I added in the code I wrote, my readFile is blank because all i was getting it to do was print every integer flat into the command line.